# Laravel 5.4 use JWTauth along with normal authentication

Tags: laravel, authentication

Me and my friend are creating an application. I'm using Laravel 5.4 as the backend and he uses Angular2 as frontend.

The Laravel project serves as a rest API with JWTauth token authentication.
Now I would like to make a small backend dashboard in the Laravel project that is only accessible by admins.

How would I go about using different authentication (with session) instead of tokens when I just browse to the api backend part?

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straightforward. Just apply the JWT auth middleware to the API routes and the normal auth middleware to your admin dashboard. You don't even need to tweak anything since JWT doesn't need changes to your table structure or need for changing the existing auth.

Build the backend dashboard using the built int auth scaffolding using the `auth` and `guest` middleware. For the api routes use the standard `api` middleware along with the `jwt.auth` middleware if you're using the `tymondesigns/jwt-auth` package. There will be no conflict with these two.

Comment: I know I can use the middlewares but this won't log me in correctly. I just browse to the /login route, which shows me the login form, I log in, and then I get the response I would get from the api. A JSON formatted user model with token and stuff...
And I'm not logged in through a session cause if I go to /home it prompts me to the login page again.

Comment: You need to separate your routes. Keep the dashboard routes in the `web.php` and use the standard auth for this. Then you have session and cookies with normal flow. Why do you want to mix both api and dashboard routes? You'll just be complicating the code base if you do.

Comment: No, I'm doing exactly what you say. I put my dashboard routes in the web.php file with middleware 'web' and the api routes are in api.php file with the auth:api middleware... Still when I login it is like the login method of the API is being triggered...

Comment: You need to re check your routes and the middleware applied to them. Run `php artisan route:list` it should give you a clear idea about your routes and the middleware applied to each one.

Comment: Well that's the problem, both logins (for api and web) are both the same, these use the LoginController@Login method... how can I make it so the web middleware uses the normal login?

Answer (score 0):

Bro use separate guard like

```
$loginUser = Auth::guard('web')->loginUsingId(12,true);
```